# Python web scraper for Tripadvisor not getting some information

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, but I'm a beginner at python and need some help with a web scraper project I've been working on!

​

Here's what I've written so far:

https://github.com/killersoda288/help/blob/master/Shortlist.py

​

I've been having some problems with it that I'm not even sure how to start googling for, would appreciate any help or advice!

​

Most serious problem is that some information seems to not be scraped at random. I've run the code a few times, and different properties will show up as 0 star rating or 0 rooms, and it's really confusing me.

​

Another not so serious problem i have is efficiency. It takes about 1 minute to finish a page. I have nothing to compare it to, but I would like to make it more efficient if possible! Thing is, I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

​

Again, thanks for reading! Would appreciate any advice :)

Comment: You may consider to use `selenium` if the page is rendered with JavaScript. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499517/beautifulsoup-parser-cant-access-html-elements) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! From what i can tell, tripadvisor purely uses html, turning off javascript on chrome still renders the whole page, is that the correct way to test it? The thread you linked also seems to have somewhat the same problem I do, in that some information is randomly not there, and the information this happens to seems random each time. I'll read up on selenium either way, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I don't think there is some content which is dynamic load. You could extract more commonable parttern. BTW '.hotels-hotel-review-about-with-photos-layout-TextItem__textitem--3CMuR span' is definitely not a pattern because it contains random string `3CMuR`. Why don't you try '.ui_bubble_rating', it's likely rating star in **start url**.

Comment: And in some item detail url, you can try 'span.room-info' to get room number directly.

Comment: I always felt there was something wrong with the selectors i used, but it seemed to work so i left it alone, thanks so much for the information! Will try changing the selectors and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summary your questions:

1. Can't extract number of room or star rating.

   You need look over more item to find more commonable pattern to extract them. I give this page a glance and find `.ui_bubble_rating` is likely for extracting star rating, `.room-info` may be helpful for room number. You could feel free to verify these. (I hope I am right :P )
2. You need iterate each item detail url, so it will take long time, that's say if one page contains 20 items, scraper need send 20+1 (1 for this page) request, how to optimize this?

   Because room number is only found in detail page, scraper should iterate each item. You could load these detail pages by multithread. `Scrapy` could finish this very well.

Comment: For 1, I changed the selector `.ui_star_rating`(Looking more for the hotel class rather than the review rating), did indeed help with extracting the star rating, seems to have no problem on that front now, thanks alot! However, `.room-info` doesn't seem to get the total number of rooms unfortunately. Will look for a better way to select `.hotels-hotel-review-about-addendum-AddendumItem__content--28NoV`.

Thanks a lot for the suggestions in 2, will take a look at Scrapy!